# Get container ID from Docker buildkit for interactive debugging

Tags: docker

It's commonly known that you can run `docker commit` against a failed build process to take a snapshot of a container for debugging purposes. The container ID is gleaned from the `running in <ID>` text. However, this text is not emitted during builds that happen with Docker's newer BuildKit `buildx` functionality.

I tried using `--progress plain` on the Docker build command, but that hasn't shown me the container IDs. Plus, I cannot run a new container from the image layer IDs (SHA hashes) that are spit out.

#### Sample BuildKit Output

Using this command:

```
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 sha256:0e70418d547c3ccb20da7b100cf4f69564bddc416652e3e2b9b514e9a732b4aa
#1 transferring dockerfile: 32B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 sha256:396b2cfd81ff476a70ecda27bc5d781bd61c859b608537336f8092e155dd38bf
#2 transferring context: 34B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest
#3 sha256:1c0b05b884068c98f7acad32e4f7fd374eba1122b4adcbb1de68aa72d5a6046f
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node
#4 sha256:5045d46e15358f34ea7fff145af304a1fa3a317561e9c609f4ae17c0bd3359df
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [internal] load build context
#5 sha256:49d7a085caed3f75e779f05887e53e0bba96452e3a719963993002a3638cb8a3
#5 transferring context: 35.17kB 0.0s done
#5 DONE 0.1s

#6 [2/4] ADD [trevortest/*, /app/]
#6 sha256:6da32965a50f6e13322efb20007ff49fb0546e2ff55799163b3b00d034a62c57
#6 CACHED
```

**Question**: How can I obtain the container IDs of the build process, during each step, specifically when using Docker BuildKit?

Comment: Do you mean to store the commit id in the middle of your pipeline with the aim of debug or inspect it if your pipeline ended with error? If your goal is to be able to choose specific image created with commit command, no matther how, I have an idea.

Comment: Yes exactly @JRichardsz. I would like to essentially use one of the successfully-built intermediate image layers to spin up a new container and inspect the filesystem.

Comment: While debugging, don't use buildkit?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer How do you turn it off for debugging?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The BuildKit works differently than the legacy docker build system. At the moment, there is no direct way to spawn a container from a step in the build and troubleshoot it.

To use the BuildKit potential up to the maximum, best approach is to organize the builds in smaller logical stages. Once the build is organized in this way, When running the builds, you can specify that you want to stop at a certain stage by using `--target`. When the target is specified, Docker creates an image with the results of the build up to that stage. You can use this container to further troubleshoot in the same way that was possible with the old build system.

Take this example. Here I have 4 stages out of which 2 are parallel stages:

```
FROM debian:9.11 AS stage-01
# Prepare for installation
RUN apt update && \
    apt upgrade -y

FROM stage-01 as stage-02
# Install building tools
RUN apt install -y build-essential

FROM stage-02 as stage-02a

RUN echo "Build 0.1" > /version.txt

FROM stage-02 as stage-03

RUN apt install -y cmake gcc g++
```

Now you can use the `--target` option to tell Docker that you want to stop at the `stage-02` as follows:

```
$ docker build -f test-docker.Dockerfile -t test . --target stage-02                                                                                                                                   [+] Building 67.5s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from test-docker.Dockerfile                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 348B                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:9.11                                   0.0s
 => [stage-01 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/debian:9.11                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-01 2/2] RUN apt update &&     apt upgrade -y                                   0.0s
 => [stage-02 1/1] RUN apt install -y build-essential                                           64.7s
 => exporting to image                                                                           2.6s
 => => exporting layers                                                                          2.5s
 => => writing image sha256:ac36b95184b79b6cabeda3e4d7913768f6ed73527b76f025262d6e3b68c2a357     0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test                                                          0.0s
```

Now you have the image with the name `test` and you can spawn a container to troubleshoot.

```
docker run -ti --rm --name troubleshoot test /bin/bash
root@bbdb0d2188c0:/# ls
```

Using multiple stages facilitates the troubleshooting, however it really speeds up the build process since the parallel branches can be build on different instances. Also, the readability of the build file is significantly improved.

Comment: This is a superb answer, Jordan! Thank you for sharing. I've marked the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's quite helpful. I'm curious how we might use this with automation though. You see, the problem is that I want Jenkins for example to be able to figure out that the `docker build` command has failed during the build of `stage-02` in particular, and to emit some information that I can automatically use to choose `stage-01` being suitable for shipping off to troubleshoot.

Comment: Validated: This answer is correct and is now the effective way to debug Docker Builds.

Comment: So no more need for dangling images for debugging! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Docker migrated from the classic builder that ran directly in the docker engine, to buildkit which runs in containerd. As a result, images built with buildkit do not leave dangling images of the intermediate steps of the build in the docker engine. For most, this is an advantage to remove clutter. However for debugging, it means you need to build your image in a way that doesn't fail.

For a small one off, you can either comment out the end of the Dockerfile to build up to the failing point, or use multiple stages for the build and use the `docker build --target` to build the working stage.

However, if you find yourself doing this a lot, I'd recommend [buildg](https://github.com/ktock/buildg) which acts as an interactive debugger for a buildkit build. It lets you insert breakpoints in the build, launch a shell from any step, and can even be used in an IDE.