# docker build taking too long

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

Below is a sample dockerfile that we are using to build a spring boot application. this build is taking around 600-700 seconds. this is just one application and we have around 40 more microservice applications. how can I shorten the build time.

````
#### Stage 1: Build the application
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.10_9-alpine as build

# Set the current working directory inside the image
WORKDIR /app

# Copy maven executable to the image
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn

# Copy the pom.xml file
COPY pom.xml .

# Build all the dependencies in preparation to go offline. 
# This is a separate step so the dependencies will be cached unless 
# the pom.xml file has changed.
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -B

# Copy the project source
COPY src src

# Package the application
RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

#### Stage 2: A minimal docker image with command to run the app 
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.10_9-alpine

ARG DEPENDENCY=/app/target/dependency

# Copy project dependencies from the build stage
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.app.AppServiceApplication"]```
````

Comment: First not building inside a docker container... how long does the build take outside? Furthermore not mapped the local cache which means every time all deps will be downloaded...

Comment: Another thing comes into my mind. How long take your tests(unit- integration tests if your have/run them)? Because 10 Minutes (600 sec) is a very long time... can you also give the number for lines of code you have in your project?

Comment: Use multistage build for all things that are common for all applications not to repeat the steps that ware already done as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66313553/2816703)

Comment: @khmarbaise - build outside the container was taking about 1min, as suspected local cache for deps were being created, changed the docker build for using local cache and it solved the issue

Comment: Do you use a local Maven mirror?

Comment: In any case, you might want to elaborate on which steps takes time and how you would expect those to be quicker.

Comment: Usually I strongly recommend not to build inside a container because the container file system is usually not that fast ... build outside and copy the resulting jar into the container...makes it easier....

Comment: @Akhil: You can look into [docker buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) - it makes possible to cache image-build dependencies.