# How to correctly install programs in docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I know that every line of `RUN ...` will add a layer to the docker image and that it is recommended to make RUN commands connected with &&. But my question is:

Is better this:

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
&& apk add openssh \
&& apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm \
&& npm install -g @angular/cli \
&& apk add openjdk11 \
&& apk add maven \
&& apk add git
```

Or this:

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add openssh
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN apk add openjdk11
RUN apk add maven
RUN apk add git
```

The first one creates just one layer but when a version of anything changes the image would have to start from the beginning, not from cash. The second approach will create more layers but when just the version of git changes only the git layer needs to be build again and all previous layers can be used from cash.

Comment: It's a good practice to minimize number of layers because it affects image size as you can see here https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers. It's not such a big deal when using multi-stage builds.

Comment: I am using a multi-stage build so should I go with the second version (lot of layers?

Comment: In that case it might be a matter of preference. I personally stick to first version because I don't have to think every time whether it's going to be used in single or multi staged build. Also in case any version changes it will only affect built time which happens once. The only time I would pick second version is when particular package takes a really long time to install and is less likely to change. In that case I would consider putting it before the multi-line install.

Comment: `RUN apk update && apk upgrade` is not efficient. The correct command is `RUN apk upgrade --no-cache`. See stackoverflow.com/a/76440791/685806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend:

- Install all the OS packages in a single `apk` invocation: there is some overhead in starting the package manager (more noticeable with `dpkg`/`apt`) and it is faster if you start it once and install several packages
- If you need to run an `update` command, always run it in the same `RUN` command as your other package-manager steps.  This avoids some trouble with Docker layer caching (again, very noticeable with `apt`) where `docker build` doesn't re-run `update`, but then it does try to run a changed `install` step; when it tries to install a package using yesterday's package index, the upload of that package that happened today deleted yesterday's file and the download will fail.
- Don't `npm install` single packages.  That means your `package.json` file is incomplete.  Add it there.

I've seen recommendations both ways as to whether or not to run a full `upgrade`.  Keeping up-to-date on security fixes is important; the underlying base images on Docker Hub also update pretty regularly.  So if your image is `FROM alpine:latest`, doing a `docker build --pull` will get you much of the effect of an explicit `apk upgrade`.

Stylistically, if I need any substantial number of packages, I find the list a little more maintainable if I sort it alphabetically and put one package on a line, but this is purely personal preference.

Putting this all together would transform your example into:

```sh
RUN apk update \
 && apk upgrade \
 && apk add \
      git \
      maven \
      nodejs \
      nodejs-npm \
      openjdk11 \
      openssh
COPY package.json package-lock.json . # includes @angular/cli
RUN npm ci
```

Don't be afraid to use multiple containers, if that makes sense.  (What's your application that uses both Java and Node together; can it be split into two single-language parts?)  Don't install unnecessary developer-oriented tools in your image.  (Does your application invoke `git` while it's running; do you install a dependency directly from GitHub; or can you remove `git`?)  Don't try to run an ssh daemon in your container.  (It breaks the "one process per container" rule which instantly makes things harder to manage; 90% of the SO examples have a hard-coded user password plus sudo rights, which is not really a security best practice; managing the credentials is essentially impossible.)

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are on the extreem, you need to try to minimize the layers for "reusability" at the same time to optimize for lower number of layers.

Based on your example, the build can be organized as follows:

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
&& apk add openssh \
&& apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm \
&& apk add openjdk11 \
&& apk add maven \
&& apk add git

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli \
```

Now I have only 2 layers, first one is bringing the OS packages and the second one dealing with the `node.js` packages. Now this can better be reused in other builds.

Once you have done this modification, you can move to multistage build where you will be able to better control and reuse the intermediate containers like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66313553/2816703)