# Docker build failure -- how to run image by sha256 hash?

Tags: docker

I'm getting an error when trying to build one of my Dockerfiles,

```
❯ docker build --build-arg env=development . --progress=plain
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 sha256:c3c9b42a729c6c2731ead1895724c3f53c55d67fe58c7ce2fcd2093556b293d6
#1 transferring dockerfile: 32B 0.0s done
#1 DONE 0.0s

...

#8 [4/4] RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production=false --non-interactive
#8 sha256:82e644b842f91e7584561a70e10518eaa645543d3d7a525140f5e26c4e93ea0d
#8 0.318 yarn install v1.22.19

...

#8 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production=false --non-interactive]: exit code: 1
------
 > [4/4] RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production=false --non-interactive:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production=false --non-interactive]: exit code: 1
```

I assume `sha256:82e644b842f91e7584561a70e10518eaa645543d3d7a525140f5e26c4e93ea0d` is the image it's trying to run `yarn install` in, yet when I try

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint sh a45dc5a92caf2f0a57593e5181c60e4fbe1f6a32ae8aa5e1cbaf30a2bd005407 -c '{ command -v zsh && exec zsh -il ;} || { command -v bash && bash -il ;} || { command -v ash && ash -il ;}'
docker: Error response from daemon: No such image: sha256:a45dc5a92caf2f0a57593e5181c60e4fbe1f6a32ae8aa5e1cbaf30a2bd005407.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

How do I get the actual image name or hash just before the build failure so that I can *docker run* it?

I believe it's using buildkit but I'm unsure how to verify. I do want buildkit.

Answer (score 2):

You have pointed the root cause that is the Buildkit build system

> Buildkit does not create intermediate images nor make the containers it runs visible in docker run (both for very good reasons).
> -- [source](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1472)

There is [a proposal](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/1104) to address this need that is in progress at the time of writing.

Alternative solutions to perform debugging with Buildkit:

- Use targets to do a partial build and the debug the output of it, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186620/get-container-id-from-docker-buildkit-for-interactive-debugging).
- Use the [buildg](https://github.com/ktock/buildg) interactive debugger.

Maybe the `buildctl` command of Buildkit can be used to perform debug but I have not checked in detail,