# When using `docker compose` how can you show each build step's intermeddiate cached container id?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It's common for docker build steps to fail. The "new" dockerx builder hides critical info for ... some reason. This makes it much more difficult to run the container where it failed and debug. Is there an easy way to enable viewing those intermediate id's?

You can use something like:

`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose build my-service`

To use the old way, but does buildkit/buildx support just viewing those ids?

Comment: [Get container ID from Docker buildkit for interactive debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186620/get-container-id-from-docker-buildkit-for-interactive-debugging) suggests this is not possible using BuildKit.  In the classic builder each layer also has its own image ID, and I also think this isn't available in BuildKit either (but I don't have a citation for that).

Comment: BuildKit seems very half assed - the concurrency is nice but at the cost of being to debug anything seems silly.