# docker-compose v2 missing build hashes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I switched from `docker-compose` v1 to v2

When building via `docker-compose build` I'm not seeing the build hashes of the steps anymore. This worked always in v1.
So I'm not able to do something like `docker run -it [hash] bash` to tinker around if an error occurs.

Comment: Is this maybe related to the Buildkit backend and not Compose _per se_; [Get container ID from Docker buildkit for interactive debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186620/get-container-id-from-docker-buildkit-for-interactive-debugging)?  That question has samples of the Buildkit output and at least one workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `Buildkit`. For now I will try to get the old output with hashes by setting the env variable `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` before executing the `build` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the op has discovered in the comments,

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose build
```

works similar to old compose.

How this just helped me:

```
...
Step 6/13 : COPY . /opt/src
 ---> 4b62f0d71552
Step 7/13 : RUN /opt/gradle-8.1.1/bin build
 ---> Running in 8bb86a4297f3
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/gradle-8.1.1/bin: Permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -c /opt/gradle-8.1.1/bin build' returned a non-zero code: 126
```

```
docker run -it 4b62f0d71552 bash
root@fec175e193c5:/opt/src# ls /opt/gradle-8.1.1/bin/
gradle  gradle.bat
```

"wdym permission denied" -> "Oh duh. I left off the binary name"

Could put `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` in your bashrc or an alias like `alias dbuild-verbose='DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose build'`